# What does the notation $A_a^n$ mean?

Tags: calculus, matrices, notation

Given a set of matrices

$$M = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&a\\0&3\end{bmatrix} \mid a \in \mathbb R\right\},$$

what does the notation $A_a^n, n \in \mathbb N$ mean?

Comment: Stock question: in what book/paper did you see these?

Comment: A Romanian high-school textbook.

Comment: Your markup was mostly right, but you tried to use curly braces without escaping them. Curly braces are grouping delimiters in $\TeX$, so you need to escape them with a backslash if you mean them literally. Also, it's better to use \mid for the vertical "such that" bar instead of just |, since it's treated as an operator and gives you the appropriate spacing.

Comment: Addendum: `bmatrix` gives bracketed matrices, which is what you seem to want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A_a$ seems to be a shorthand for a typical matrix in $M$. Then $A_a^n$ is the $n$-th power of $A_a$.

Comment: Yes, it appears that's what it means. Thanks!